# Parcel ID Mapping (brainstorming)

Tags: postgis, ms-access, arcgis-explorer, parcel

In my project I have a table full of residential properties by Parcel_ID.  Table 2 is a TIGER streets shapefile.  I would like to build a query in MS Access displaying all properties within a mile radius of my selected property from table 1.

[image: project structure]

My questions are :

1. Should I use open-source postgis (spatial databases) and build this project in SQL 2008 to query off map location rather than tabular data?
2. Or Should I use a FileGeodatabase to import the shapefile into MS ACCESS?

I have the shapefile loaded in ArcGIS explorer - but not sure how to export.

6/17/2012 update****  I posted the state parcel tables below:

**County Mapping Parcel Table**
OBJECTID    PARCEL_TAG  **PARCEL_I**    PARCEL_C    LOTNUM  SUBDIVISIO  SUBDIVNUM   STNUMBER    PRE_DIR STREET_NAM  SUFFIX  SUF_DIR FULL_STNAM  CITY    COUNTY  STATE   TOWNSHIP    ZIPCODE ESTSQFT BLOCK   MODDATE STATUS  **SHAPE_AREA**  **SHAPE_LEN**  |
1   1251683 8011477 8011477     7809    1723    4015    N   KENWOOD AVE     KENWOOD AVE INDIANAPOLIS    MARION  IN  WASHINGTON  46208   5280    1004            *****5279.952157****    ***343.9990607***

Comment: 1. PostGIS will do all of the spatial calculations faster than any shape/geodatabase or MS Access file. Rather than ArcExplorer QGIS would be used to visualise your results direct form postgis

Comment: You could also consider putting your spatial and tabular data into [sqlite/spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins) if you want to keep your data file based instead of installing server-side software.

Comment: To clarify, does your parcel table have a geometry column, or is it only attributes?  If this is the case, then you will need to do geocoding as well as a simple select by distance query.

Comment: I have a state table with Parcel_ID. I have another table with Parcel_ID by SHAPE_AREA AND SHAPE_LEN provided by state mapping department.  All my tables link on Parcel_ID as the primary key.

Comment: I would be more interested in data analysis in Access VS. a visual product in Arc Explorer.  Does anyone know how to form a distance query?

Comment: Access is really the wrong tool for this. If you need it for generating reports, I'd suggest you put the data in sqlite/spatialite, create a view for the calculations you need and connect to the sqlite/spatialite db via ODBC.

Comment: Derrick: Regarding Get Spatial's question, can you clarify if the Parcel table is spatial or not? Does it have a geometry column? Lon/Lat coordinates? And another question: how will the Parcel table connect to the TIGER/line shapefile? I don't see any reference to Parcels in any of the TIGER data, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The Parcel Table has "SHAPE_AREA" & "SHAPE_LEN" (I posted a shot of the table above).  I do not see any Lon/Lat Coordinates - maybe that is what I am missing and not understanding.  I called a data analyst with TIGER data and TIGER data does not link to any parcel data (your are correct Micha)

Comment: Thanks (Sean) for your input on sqlite/spatialit.  A state mapping expert referred me to ArcGIS for this project - but I'm worried that won't help me pull in reporting analysis for the mile radius reports I need.  If sqlite/spatialit databases are the way to go can anyone suggest any good programs?  Thanks everyone

Comment: If your parcel table has columns for "Shape_area" and "Shape_len" then it must have originated as a shapefile. Can you obtain that shapefile? If so, it would be easy to pull it into a spatialite database and run a query for all parcels within a certain radius of a given parcel.

Comment: I can contact the state rep and get the original shapefile.  I will contact them today.  What kind of spatialite database to you recommend?